# Does this make an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I'm trying to make a dynamically allocated array. To do that I'm trying to make an array of pointers. I used typedef to define the pointer type and tried to create the array of pointers using this code.

```
emprec * arrptr = new emprec[size];
```

my question is, is this the correct way to create an array of pointers? If not, what would be a better way of doing so.

emprec is defined in the program as seen below

```
struct emprec
{
int id;
float salary;
};
typedef emprec * emprecptr;
typedef emprec arr[MAXDBSIZE];
```

(I am a student and I'm trying to learn more about dynamic allocation)

---

After the kind help of you guys on here, it was made clear that I originally made an array of emprec which would be an array of structs. I didn't want that. Changing the code to

```
emprecptr* DBarray = new emprecptr[dbsize];
```

now gives me an array of pointers.

Comment: It really depends what `emprec` is. If `emprec` is a pointer then you have a array of pointers, if not then you don't, you have an array of `emprec`.

Comment: You likely should not have a dynamic array of raw pointers. Instead perhaps a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<emprec>>`

Comment: You have an array of emprec's, whatever those are.

Comment: "I used typedef to define the pointer type" don't do that! Don't hide pointer types in a typedef. Also, you should learn modern C++ idioms first. Then, after you are comfortable with that if you want to go into the nitty gritty details of implementations, sure, go for pointers and manual memory management. Or learn C instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
struct emprec
{
    int id;
    float salary;
};
```

then, no

```
emprec * arrptr = new emprec[size];
```

is not an array of pointers, but an array of `emprec`'s. But since you also had `typedef emprec * emprecptr;`, then

```
emprecptr * arrptr = new emprecptr[size];
```

*would* be an array of pointers (to `emprec`). Without the `typedef` you would have to write it as:

```
emprec* * arrptr = new emprec*[size];
```

But as you can see, the `typedef` simplifies the understanding of the code and possibly, makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First point is not to confuse an *array of pointers* with a *pointer to an array*. You said the first, so I'm going to take you at your word. But what follows is misleading if you really meant the second.

In general to create a dynamic array of `T` you write

```
T* arr = new T[size];
```

Since you want an array of pointers `T` must be a pointer. For instance here is how to create an array of integer pointers.

```
int** arr = new int*[size];
```

Similarly an array of pointers to `emprec` would be

```
emprec** arr = new emprec*[size];
```

This can be simplifed using the typedef in your question to

```
emprecptr* arr = new emprecptr[size];
```

Comment: I think I'm understanding what you are saying. I feel like that's leading to exactly what I need, I edited my original post to include what emprec is, but I'm starting to think what I originally wrote is actually an array of structs, but don't quote me on that. With the additional information I provided how would that change the solution I'm looking for?

Comment: @Amxela an array of structs is a completely different thing to an array of pointers. I think you have the confusion I mentioned in my first sentence.

Comment: @Amxela In short the code you have in your question is correct for an array of structs and my answer isn't helpful

Comment: Yeah I was just confused on what I originally put down. Seeing your edit makes way more sense to me now. If I'm getting this right I'm creating a new emprecptr called arr and setting it equal to an emprecptr array. Which results in a dynamically allocated array of pointers. I actually needed what you put though I just messed up what I originally created.